# Alert con asp.net framework

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, mvc

Estoy trabajando con MVC en asp.net framework intentando usar un try catch para evitar un error, pero no se si hay una manera de enviar un alert de Javascript en el catch, ya lo he intentado de la siguiente manera e inclusive pasandole simplemente el mesaje pero no me resulta. Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida. Gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Viendo que haces un RedirectToAction, podrias usar TempData en el catch TempData['EliminarError'] =  ex.ToString(); y recoger ese dato en el index si se encuentra lanzas el alert con javascript. Aunque lo correcto seria que implementaras un control mas robusto.

Comment: El cierre de la etiqueta es: </script> (primero la diagonal)

Comment: Muchas gracias @StialManstike, me sirvio el TempData llamandolo desde el Index. Te agradezco mucho!